# Prestashop Product Customizations - Saving To Cart

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prestashop

Prestashop 1.6

I created a module that adds a form to the product page.  I used the prestashop module generator to create a basic bare-bones module.  It doesn't do anything except add a form to the product page via a hook.

I am using the default-bootstrap theme.

The form is generated via a .tpl file that is based on which category the product is in (i.e. if it's in category A, then it shows form A).  The form looks like this:

```
<form id="engraving_selection">
    <h3>Engraving Options</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="engraving" value="Engrave-Different" id="engrave_different" checked="checked">Unique engraving for each item<br />
    <input type="radio" name="engraving" value="Engrave-Same" id="engrave_same">The engraving would the same on each item<br />
    <input type="radio" name="engraving" value="No-Engraving" id="no_engraving">I would not like engraving<br />
</form>
<form id="engraving_options">
    <h4>Engraving Text</h4>
    <div id="items">
        <div class="item" data-position="1">
            <h4 id="engraving-item">Item 1</h4>
            <label>Engraving Line 1: </label>
            <input type="text" class="engraving-input" name="line1-trophy" id="item1">
            <br />
            <label>Engraving Line 2: </label>
            <input type="text" class="engraving-input" name="line2-trophy" id="item1">
            <br />
            <label>Engraving Line 3: </label>
            <input type="text" class="engraving-input" name="line3-trophy" id="item1">
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The form is a selection of radio inputs, followed by 3 text inputs.  If the user changes the quantity, an additional 3 inputs are added accordingly via javascript (so if the user changes the quantity to '2', then 2 sets of the 3 inputs appear for customization on each product).

I would like some guidance on saving these inputs and the information the user has entered when the user clicks 'add to cart' so that it may be retrieved / edited later (before the user checks out).

Some research has led me to ajax-cart.js and this function specifically:

```
add : function(idProduct, idCombination, addedFromProductPage, callerElement, quantity, whishlist)
```

What is the best way to do pass in that data so it can be saved/retrieved?

Ultimately I would like it to be included on the order (obviously) and saved to the database with that order for future use.

I know the plugin Attribute Wizard Pro exists - but I'm looking to expand my knowledge and make something on my own.

If there are other ways to go about this that would be cleaner/easier I'm open to those suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a totally fresh solution, but it will take long time and many lines of code.

The best choice would be to use Prestashop built-in product **Customization** option.

1. Go to Backoffice and select a single `Product` `Edit` > `Customization` tab.
2. Add `Text fields` number which you can think can be a maximum for one product.

[image: Product Customization tab]

3. Add some `javascript` to your product page hiding / showing these text fields inputs (as they all would be visible on default).

   You can add your `javascript` code to:

   - `themes/[your-theme]/product.js` file (*preferred*) - it will be loaded only on the product page,
   - `themes/[your-theme]/js/autoload/[any-file-name].js` - it will be loaded on all pages.

   Please be sure to add buggy free code :)

Done!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am familiar with product customization, but I need more than just text inputs.  I guess writing this myself is the only way - or move to a new platform.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see anything in your question what could be considered as "more than text inputs" :) Can you specify?

Comment: You're right.  I should have given this as an example: http://www.pushpindesigns.com/tgpresta/prestashop/trophies/8-football-resin.html

Comment: The user picks from a radio list and the text inputs are generated dynamically.  

I actually have that part working fine and it works as it should.  I just don't know how to save that to the DB appropriately and add it to the cart item.

Comment: Yes, the most complicated part of this task is to add data to the database in proper places. But Prestashop already did it with "customisations" options. So I still think you should attach your javascript (showing or hiding text inputs on radio switch, adding generated text or anything else you need) to the Prestashop part which is done and working fine, which is linking text inputs to orders details.

Comment: What is the best way to go about that?  What section / module in prestashop do I need to add the JS to?  I cannot find anything in documentation about it.

Comment: If the data is not something you want to perform queries on later, then you can just create a single text field as in the answer above, hide it with css (or set it as a type=hidden if pos) then serialize all your generated fields as json and store the result in that field

Comment: Thanks Indre & Steve - appreciate the help. I have been able to serialize the form submission and insert it into the value of a 'hidden' customization form.

It's a workaround, but it works!